# Nginx proxy for directory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using an image server with grunt on to resize my images. However, when a user visits the website they get an mixed content warning.

I thought one way to stop this is to proxy the request for the user. I've tried a few things but I'm not sure what to do if I'm honest.

Image server: http://www.imageserver.com/resize/1/12/77/6160877_272331112333_1_XLARGE.jpg?w=720&h=480

I would like to add the following to the anchor tag: https://www.myserver.com/resize/1/12/77/6160877_272331112333_1_XLARGE.jpg?w=720&h=480

I tried:

```
location /resize {
    proxy_pass http://www.imageserver.com;
    proxy_set_header Host www.imageserver.com;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Did you reload/restart nginx after changing the config?

Comment: I'm getting a 404

Comment: Try to use `curl` with `-vvv`option and look which server gets upset and whether nginx really forwards it, narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Myron for giving me some confidence I was on the right track. The answer is:

```
location ~/resize {
    proxy_pass http://www.imageserver.com;
    proxy_set_header Host www.imageserver.com;
}
```